# Send post request after reset button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have button on my page

```
<button type="reset" class="abort-selection">Clear</button>
```

When i click it all field and checkboxes reseting to default. Thats ok.

Now I want to send post request after this button is clicked.
I do this on existing send Post function

```
<script>


$(function() {

$('div.list input[type=checkbox]').on('change',onValueChange);     
$('div.selector select').on('change', onValueChange);
$('button[type=reset]').on('click', onValueChange);

function onValueChange() {

        var Checked = {};
        var Selected = {};
    // Hold all checkboxes
        $('div.list input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {
            var $el = $(this);
            var name = $el.attr('name');
            if (typeof (Checked[name]) === 'undefined') {
                Checked[name] = [];
            }
            Checked[name].push($el.val());
        });
    // Hold all dropdowns
        $('div.list select').each(function () {

            var $el = $(this);
            var name = $el.attr('name');

                if (!!$el.val()) {
                    Selected[name] = $el.val();
                }
        });

// Put all together to POST 
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Search.asp',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $.param(Selected) + "&" + $.param(Checked),
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#ExSearchForm").html(data)
                .find('div.list input[type=checkbox],div.selector select').each(function () {
                    var $el = $(this);
                    var name = $el.attr('name');
                    var value = $el.attr('value');

                    if (Checked[name] && Checked[name].indexOf(value) !== -1 ) {
                        $el.prop('checked', true);
                    }
                    if (Selected[name]) {
                        $el.val(Selected[name]);
                    }
                });
        }
    });
};
});
</script>
```

In this way reset not working, seem like `onValueChange` function prevent reseting and do own function.

So how to reset and after send this Post request with reseted checkboxes and dropdowns?

Comment: did you debuged with breakpoint. in chrome it's `cmd+alt+i -> Sources -> select your js and set the break point`. validate if you are reaching the method

Comment: Yes, there are no errors, it seems like `<button type="reset"` not working when calling `onclick` event `$('button[type=reset]').on('click', onValueChange);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your form is submitting this will work
 
Put `$('#form-id').reset();` end of the ajax success function
Replace " **#form-id** " with your form id

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/Search.asp',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $.param(Selected) + "&" + $.param(Checked),
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#ExSearchForm").html(data)
                .find('div.list input[type=checkbox],div.selector select').each(function () {
                    var $el = $(this);
                    var name = $el.attr('name');
                    var value = $el.attr('value');

                    if (Checked[name] && Checked[name].indexOf(value) !== -1 ) {
                        $el.prop('checked', true);
                    }
                    if (Selected[name]) {
                        $el.val(Selected[name]);
                    }
                });
             $('#form-id').reset();
        }
    });
```

Try put these codes

```
//this will reset your checkboxes
$('div.list input[type=checkbox]').removeAttr('checked');
//this will reset your select box
$('div.selector select option').removeAttr('selected');
```

Comment: I dont have Forms all in divs, and also i want reset before post not after

Comment: Sorry.. I updated it now. you can put those two lines anywhere you need. it will reset your checkboxes and select box

Comment: sorry my bad.. put those two codes before ajax function. it will reset the form before post..